# Marketo - REST API field for Microsoft Type

Tags: marketo

In case of a sync between Marketo and Microsoft Dynamics the "Microsoft Type" field is added to leads data.

The issue is that there is no access to "Microsoft Type" field via REST API. I don't find its REST API name in the export fields document.

Any idea why it's not available or anyone knows the REST API name for Microsoft Type field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a custom field(Marketo Microsoft Type) and a campaign where I assign Microsoft Type value to the new created custom field

Answer (score 0):

Well, we integrated our Marketo instance with Salesforce, so I'm not 100% sure how the Type field is called in case of Microsoft Dynamics. However, based on the Salesforce integration (where the API name of the SFDC Type field is *sfdcType*) I would expect it to be "*microsoftType*".

To make sure, I would make a call to the [Describe Lead](http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Leads/describeUsingGET_2) API endpoint –at `GET /rest/v1/leads/describe.json`– to get a list of the field names available on the Lead object.
The response looks something like this:

```js
[
    {
        "id":4,
        "displayName":"Company Name",
        "dataType":"string",
        "length":255,
        "rest": {
            "name":"company",
            "readOnly":false
        },
        "soap": {
            "name":"Company",
            "readOnly":false
        }
    }
    // … other field descriptions
    {
        "id":90,
        "displayName":"SFDC Type",
        "dataType":"string",
        "length":50,
        "rest": {
            "name":"sfdcType",// <- REST API name
            "readOnly":true
        }
    }
    // … other field descriptions
]
```

Comment: I've made that describeLead call to get the fields details but Microsoft Type field is not there. I know when integrating with Salesforce we get that field and is available in REST API but it looks like when it comes to Microsoft Dynamic there is an issue.